# cudaHostRegister returns cudaErrorInvalidValue

Tags: cuda, mmap, memory-mapped-files

I have opened a file in READONLY mode. Have mapped it in the host memory using `mmap` as follows

```
uint8_t *data_ptr = (uint8_t *) mmap(NULL,NumOfBytes,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE, file_descriptor, 0);
```

The mmap returns with NO ERROR.

Now i want to lock the memory using `cudaHostRegister` so that i can use **data_ptr** in cuda API `cudaMemcpyAsync`(..)

```
cudaHostRegister(data_ptr,NumOfBytes,cudaHostRegisterDefault);
```

`cudaHostRegister` returns an error i.e. `cudaErrorInvalidValue`

The description of `cudaErrorInvalidValue` says the following:

> This indicates that one or more of the parameters passed to the API
>   call is not within an acceptable range of values

Does anyone knows why the above function complains ?

**Edit 1:**

`mmap` doesn't return the physical location of the mapped file so i took two pointers. One for `malloc` and another for mapping the file.

```
/* This ptr will hold the physical location of the file */
    ptr = malloc(size)

/* Virtual address of mapped file */
    tmp_ptr = mmap(file)

/* Copy the contents of file to the ptr */
    memcpy(ptr,tmp_ptr,size)

/* unmapping the file */
    munmap(tmp_ptr,..)

/* Register the ptr */
    cudaHostRegister(ptr,size,..)
```

This technique worked but there are two issues with this approach.

1) `memcpy` takes time for big files.

2) `memcpy` fails (*segmentation fault*) for files ~4GB.

Though i have memory free space available ~10GB.

Comment: I am highly skeptical this can work. Managed and pinned/mapped memory allocations need to be physical memory which can be accessed by DMA over the PCI-e bus. Further, read only memory makes no sense in the context of managed memory. That isn't supported by the GPU virtual machine memory space model

Comment: I agree with @talonmies, I'm also pretty sure it can not work for same reasons

Comment: Have replaced RO with RW in both i.e. open(..) and mmap(..), still the same error message.

Comment: @NoumanTajik: Right, because you can't register (which implies page locking) a mmaped file. The allocation must be backed by physical memory

Comment: Thank you talonmies. I found an alternative solution to this problem. I mapped my file and copied it to malloc-allocated location. Then use cudaHostRegister(..) to register it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The approach that worked for me is the following:

1) Mapped  the file using `mmap`

2) Pinned it using `mlock`

3) Registered it using `cudaHostRegister`